# Python/ Numpy Changing all „ ,“ to „.“ in an array

Tags: python, numpy, file

I am trying to extract data from a .txt file which embodies certain measurement values that I would like to use inside Python. I am doing this with the numpy module (numpy.genfromtxt), which saves the values into an array.

Nevertheless, whenever there is a decimal value, it is written with a comma (1,456 f.e.), which Python does not accept as a decimal. Sadly, this is the way that the data has been given to me. Now, I would like to write a Python Code that goes through all elements of the array, basically looks out for commas and changes them to dots (I have multiple files and I would like to automate this process, even though I could technically do it manually :) ).

As I have started programming with C and C++, I would have done this with pointers and loops. Nevertheless, the pointer concept does not seem to exist in Python or is at least not advised. I would be very glad if any of you could please tell me whether there is a way to advance this problem in Python. Thank you very much!

Comment: How are the values delimited in the file, are they also delimited by a comma?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Please give more details. We cannot answer you if you do not include the code you wrote yet / sample data / and full error messages
about your trial to solve this problem, so we can reproduce and help.
See MRE here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

read the file content and replace the "," characters like so:

```
with open('file.txt.','r') as f:
    content = f.read().replace(',','.')

# do whatever with "content"
```